# RSpec check the count of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am testing my controller action for practice. In my controller, I just want to get all the distinct products by name from my database:

```
  def shop
    @products = Product.select('distinct on (name) *').sort_by &:order
  end
```

I've checked this manually and it works fine. Now I am setting up my test using my RSpec and I want to test that @products is an array greater than 0:

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #shop' do
    it 'should get all proudcts' do
      get :shop
      expect(assigns(:products).count).to be > 0 
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I've tried several different combinations of the expect... but it keeps telling me that its either nil or 0, which I know it's not. How can I test that an array is greater 0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
expect(assigns(:products)).to_not be_empty
```

This works because the array responds to `empty?`. Another way could be

```
expect(assigns(:products).count).to be_positive
```

Because integers respond to `positive?`

While if you wanted to check an actual count

```
expect(assigns(:products).count).to eq 1
```

Comment: Alternatively to these options, you can create your own matcher. Here is an example. https://gist.github.com/danielwestendorf/84058a8b458a4f3cfe87e13bd8b9ca9c

Comment: Thanks Ursus. I actually found the problem. I didn't seed my test database with data so I had it right, just didn't set everything up right. smh.

Answer (score 3):

You could also turn it around a bit into the following:

```rb
expect(assigns(:products)).to have_attributes(count: be_positive)
```

This allows you to use `subject`, like this for example:

```rb
subject { assigns(:products) }

it { is_expected.to have_attributes(count: be_positive) }
```

Comment: better answer, because array/object content is shown in exception using this approach